# Opencv2.4x doesn't work in ubuntu 18.04, undefined reference to cv::imread

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I compiled Opencv-2.4.9 and Opencv-2.4.13 without CUDA in Ubuntu18.04. But I got the following error while reading pictures in my code:

```
CMakeFiles/mat_tensor.dir/mat_tensor.cpp.o: In function `main':
mat_tensor.cpp:(.text+0x1157): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
mat_tensor.cpp:(.text+0x11b5): undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::string const&, int)'
mat_tensor.cpp:(.text+0x122e): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/mat_tensor.dir/build.make:116: recipe for target 'mat_tensor' failed
make[2]: *** [mat_tensor] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mat_tensor.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mat_tensor.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <torch/script.h>
#include <string>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string p = "/home/dai/scripts/pytorch_chineseocr/pictures/1.png";
    Mat img = imread(p);
    namedWindow("img");
    imshow("img",img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

And My CMakeLists.txt if as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(mat_tensor)

SET(OpenCV_DIR /home/dai/library/opencv-2.4.13.6/build)
SET(Torch_DIR /home/dai/library/libtorch_cpu/share/cmake/Torch)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)

add_executable(mat_tensor mat_tensor.cpp)
target_link_libraries(mat_tensor ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(mat_tensor ${TORCH_LIBRARIES})
```

I have been working on this problem the whole day, how can I fix this problem? Looking forward to your replay.

Comment: Can you try adding torch libraries line before opencv libraries?

Comment: You use `OpenCV_LIBRARIES` variable which is probably not set. The effect of `find_package(OpenCV)` depends on whether you have `FindOpenCV.cmake` script in **your project** or you use script `OpenCVConfig.cmake` which comes with OpenCV installation. Consult the actual script about the proper way for use results of `find_package(OpenCV)`. E.g., this is a [template for OpenCVConfig.cmake](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/templates/OpenCVConfig.cmake.in) script, description of its usage is at the beginning of the script.

Comment: BTW, there is a simple [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) about using OpenCV in CMake project. Why do not follow it?

Comment: The code works when I remove torch from my project.

Comment: Adding torch libraries line before opencv libraries doesn't solve my problem.